# How to read research papers?

Tags: phd, reading

I am reading some papers from Arxiv which were advised by a professor. Also the papers are published by a professors. My question is as follows: How to prove the professor that I have read the paper (advised by him)? Actually, I don't want to say just "sir, I have read the paper advised by you". If I truly read the papers then I might get a chance to be research student under him.

Please advise me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read papers of professors?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/119434/how-to-read-papers-of-professors)

Comment: Yes I read it previously but it answers me "how to read a paper"

Comment: Are you trying to ask something like: "how do I demonstrate that I read and understood a professor's paper to the professor in question?" or are you just trying to ask: "what is the best way to try to read a research paper that was recommended to me?"

Comment: @NAMcMahon Yes, I am asking about something like: "how do I demonstrate that I read and understood a professor's paper to the professor in question". Actually, I want to convince the professor that I read some of his paper and understood those well. How will I convince him?

Comment: @user454229 Did you read it and do you understand it well?

Comment: You probably don't understand everything in the paper. Then ask your professor questions related to things you don't understand well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove that you read a paper, you should read it carefully by analyzing the main results and identify the contribution. You should also understand why a hypothesis is made and whether if it is optimal or not. Sometimes you might find some errors or improve some results. In this way, you can prove that you truly read a research paper.

Answer (score 0):

Understand the motivation for the paper, how it contributes to its particular research community, and note any clever twists or innovations it introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Write a short (one page) summary of the paper, giving key results. Include any important insights you obtained by reading the paper. End your summary with questions you might have that the professor might be able to answer. Send a copy to the professor.

Note that in some fields like mathematics, the "key results" might include things not stated as such. An interesting and unique proof technique or methodology might be the most important contribution.

The insights and questions are just as important as the summary, actually.

If you have periodic meetings with the professor, bring the summaries along with you.

Bonus: If you can think of some logical extension to the paper that might require research, mention that also.

Going beyond your question, it would be useful personally if you add the paper to a personal bibliographic list along with your summary. Perhaps include things referenced in that paper that you think would be worth exploring.